# Simple UDP application not receiving in Python

Tags: python, sockets, networking, raspberry-pi, udp

I am trying to create a small program that sends a Hello World to my laptop from my Raspberry Pi, I am on the same network however, the code below seems not to work. I feel like it might be a firewall issue.

#### Raspberry Pi's code

```
import socket

ip = "127.0.0.1"
port = 5005
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((ip, port))
message = b"Hello World"
sock.sendto(message, (ip, port))
```

#### Laptop's code

```
import socket
ip = "127.0.0.1"
port = 5005
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind((ip, port))

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) 
    print("received message: %s" % data)
```

There are no error messages, just no data is displayed.
Should be noted that when both of these files are ran on the same machine they work however, when on two different machines they do not.

Comment: Make sure the ip you entered in your code is the ip from the other machine and not just "127.0.0.1".
If you're running a Linux based distro on your laptop you can check if your code is listening with "netstat -tulpn | grep 5005".
And third check if your firewall allows UDP traffic on port 5005.

Comment: You can bind to all interfaces for listening via ip `0.0.0.0`, but when sending, as @SvenArends said, you need the exact ip address of your target machine.

Comment: @SvenArends when using the laptop's IP I get the error `OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address` How would I go about checking if one specific port is blocked?

Comment: I have fixed my problem, it came down to the bind function, the IP argument needed to be an empty string and not the laptop's IP address

Comment: > Make sure the ip you entered in your code is the ip from the other machine and not just "127.0.0.1"
...

Correction, I meant the client-size.
When a server is told to listen on 0.0.0.0 that means "listen on every available network interface", with the server on 127.0.0.1 you're limited to local traffic only.